# ColdFusion loop over xml escape xml tags

Tags: xml, loops, coldfusion

Yes, looping over XML is easy. Everything is easy in ColdFusion ... BUT when I loop and get values I get both values and XML tags.

For example in an XML string with countries, I should be getting just "Australia". However, I am getting:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<country>Australia</country>
```

Of course, I can just `reReplace` so I get only the value and none of the tags. However, if I get a XML with lots of data, I don't want to loop over everything and clean each XML item in order to get what I want. Does anyone have any workaround for that?

PS: It is a valid XML

Here is the code:

```
<cfset feedResult=XmlParse(grc.filecontent)>  
 <cfloop array="#feedResult.content.states.state#" index="kl">
     <tr>
        <td>
            #kl.st#
        </td>
        <td>
            #kl.country#
        </td>
      </tr> 
  </cfloop>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `xmlText` to get the value of a node i.e.,

```
 <cfset feedResult=XmlParse(grc.filecontent)>  
 <cfloop array="#feedResult.content.states.state#" index="kl">
     <tr>
        <td>
            #kl.st.xmlText# <!--- nodeName.xmlText --->
        </td>
        <td>
            #kl.country.xmlText# <!--- nodeName.xmlText --->
        </td>
      </tr> 
  </cfloop>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that was it !!