# ColdFusion 11 xml markup is included when referencing node value

Tags: xml, coldfusion, xml-parsing, coldfusion-11

I'm trying to get the value of some xml nodes but for some reason it is returning the markup around the value also. Any idea why and how I can get the value only? Below is an example of my issue.

Here is the xml dump
[XML cfdump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufhz5.png)

Then I am referencing the XML like so.

```
<cfset ResponseXML = #xmlparse(getOrders)#>
<cfset OrderNodes = ResponseXML.list.elements.order>
<cfoutput>#OrderNodes.orderDate#</cfoutput>
```

Then when I see it on the screen it looks correct and it gives me the date from the xml on the screen. If I try to insert it into a date type field in the database it tells me it can't convert to string so I start looking at the view source and it is actually returning this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><orderDate>2017-02-21T20:48:11.000Z</orderDate>
```

So why is it returning xml markup when I reference the node value like that?
How can I just get the value and not that extra markup?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ColdFusion loop over xml escape xml tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37454952/coldfusion-loop-over-xml-escape-xml-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your dump shows, you need to reference the data using the `XmlText` element of the parsed structure.

```
<cfoutput>#OrderNodes.orderDate.XmlText#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks so much. Just needed the extra eyes.